# Matlab: Creating mathematical functions

Tags: matlab, function, math

I am new to Matlab and trying to do some mathematical problems
I knew how to create function using the inline method,
However i need to know how to use it to define functions with different domains.
For example:

```
  g(t) =  1   for t<=50
          2   for t> 50
```

how is this possible?
I have created a time vector using T = [0:0.01:100] but how to relate between the two?
Thanks all for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), and define it making use of [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
g = @(t) (t<=50) + 2*(t>50)
```

Example:

```
>> t = 45:52;
>> g(t)

ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution for this is admittedly somewhat unintuitive if you're not familiar with Matlab yet:

```
function y = g(t)
y = ones(size(t));
y(t>50) = 2;
end
```

If by "inline method" you mean generating an anonymous function handle, that gets tricker, but in this case is possible in an even more idiomatic way:

```
g = @(t) (t>50) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if to check the argument and define a function in the usual way:

```
function output = g(t)
if t<=50
   output=1
end
   output=2
```